# Installing Composer for PHP

Tags: php, oauth, installation, composer-php, etsy

I need to install `PHPoAuthLib` in my website. Instructions says:

> "This library can be found on Packagist. The recommended way to
>   install this is through composer."

However, I don't have `Composer` installed, and I am having a hard time to understand how it is applied to a site.

Can anyone give me instructions to install Composer? (I am running Windows, only have FTP access to the server and using iPage as a host).

Comment: Install via composer may be the **recommended** way but not the **only** way. Just try to download the src from github and push it onto your server via ftp. I bet you can load it from there since it's only php. Check out the `bootstrap.php` in the `src/OAuth` directory of the project.

Comment: Should I just upload the 'src' folder to my source directory and then start using it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being unable to google "install composer".

Comment: I think the question is more about how to deal with composer when you have only ftp access to a server. In which case I simply wouldn't use it (though it's probably possible). @samyb8: Yes, I would try to upload the source folder and include the `bootstrap.php` script via require_once, which should register the autoloader. Then you should be able to use the project's classes (If you are familiar with namespaces).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work since there is a line in bootstrap as follows: "require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';" where the library relies on an autoload.php that seems to be part of Composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation instructions for Composer can be found on http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md